# User32.DLL SetFocus fails with Win32 error 5:Access is denied

Tags: c#, pinvoke, access-denied, user32

The code below does the following

PushWindowToFront():

- gets the current process id for reference later
- calls user32.dll function **EnumWindows** with callback **EnumWindowsCallback** method
- EnumWindows then iterates through each window and calls callback for each

Callback:

- Check if window thread process id is same as current process id
- if so, check if Window text begins "Select "
- if so, call user32.dll function SetFocus on window handle
- check & print last win32 error

However, it always returns win32 error 5 - "Access is denied". Why wouldn't the application have access to call this function against a window belonging to the same process?

.

```
    public void PushWindowToFront()
    {
        currentProcessId = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

        Win32Methods.EnumWindowsCallbackDelegate callback = new Win32Methods.EnumWindowsCallbackDelegate(this.EnumWindowsCallback);

        Win32Methods.EnumWindows(callback, (IntPtr) 0);
    }

    public bool EnumWindowsCallback(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        uint i = 0;

        Win32Methods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out i);

        if (currentProcessId == i)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(512);

            Win32Methods.GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);

            if (sb.ToString().Split(' ')[0].ToLower().Equals("select"))
            {
                IntPtr result = Win32Methods.SetFocus(hWnd);
                Console.WriteLine("Window found: {0}\r\nSetting focus...\r\nResult: {1}\r\nLastError: {2}",
                    sb.ToString(), result, Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `result`?

Comment: The thread matters as well, a window is owned by the thread that created it.

Answer (score 4):

I have received this exact situation; my understanding is that the "SetFocus" is the culprit. I resolved the error by replacing "SetFocus" with "SetForegroundWindow"

```
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, winName)
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
```